# How to count span inside ul which have li inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery

have a code structure like this :

```
<ul class="ulNotif">
<span id="notiftype1"></span>
<span id="notiftype2"></span>
<span id="notiftype3"></span>
</ul>
```

I sent li with jquery to each span. Every span will have li if the data match with the condition.

I tried to count with `$(".ulNotif span li").length` but still 0 value.
How to count span which have li inside it with javascript? Thanks

Comment: How about using valid HTML? The ONLY valid HTML inside a UL is LI. Not SPAN.

Comment: It should be `.ulNotif`, not `#ulNotif`, because it's a class, not an ID.

Comment: Yeah, make a normal list then append `<spans>` within `<li>`.

Comment: If i didn't use span then if there are 3 notif which mean 3 li inside it...then the highest li will replacing another li. So it just view 1 li in the notif

Comment: Sorry before, i miss type. I mean .ulNotif not #ulNotif

Answer (score 2):

@junkfoodjunkie is correct. You should use `<li>` tags as direct descendants of `<ul>`. Nonetheless, your code should look like this:

`$(".ulNotif span li").length`

Your `<ul>` has a .class, not an #ID

**EDIT**: This works totally find for me: returns 3

```
$('.ulNotif span').each((index, child) => {
  $(child).append('<li>')
})

console.log($('.ulNotif span li').length)
```

Comment: Sorry i miss type on it...i mean i did like you says :D

Comment: it doesn't work for me..
i call 2 ajax for 2 type of notification which is will stored inside span.

Comment: @user2236102 you're going to need to provide the code for that, then. What you have asked has been answered; if there is something more complex at play, please share it.